# Continue training LSTM model on new data

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'am pretty much new in machine learning world, currently struggling trying to find out how to continue in training after model load. Found few similar topics, but still can't figure it out.

I got model for time-series forecasting and want to re-train it, once new data shows up (data_original+data_new). Problem is, if I load the model and want to continue in training, it seems to start from scratch. This happens even when I use exactly the same setup and data, which were used for training original model.

pseudo code:

```
    def update_model(model, data, batch_size, updates):

        X, y = train[:, :-n_seq], train[:, -n_seq:]
        X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], n_lag, n_features)
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

        for i in range(updates):               
            model.fit(X, y,epoch=1,b_size=1,verbose=0, shuffle=False)
            model.reset_states()
        return model

    model = load_model("multivariete_model.h5")
```

Comment: Maybe use model.train_on_batch() instead of calling fit again

Comment: @mickmick1, Did you successfully run the code for updating the Lstm, if yes. Please share the code with me , I am in this stage too !

Answer (score 1):

You're telling keras to recompile the model every time you call

```
model.compile()
```

and you're doing that everytime you call `update_model` with:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Remove that line and training will continue from previous state.

Comment: just removed that line and run the code with evaluation of model after 10 epochs:

     original:  0.6359964006149502
     retrained:  0.002937551016101346  :/

Comment: which is slightly better but still not solving the issue

Comment: we'll at some point you're going to hit threshold of what the model could learn given the current parameters. so unless you have another issue I imagine is current behaviour is as expected

Comment: Don't really think so @orsonady , I tried to proof your theory with training  and re-training several models, but it starts from scratch every single time.

Comment: @parsethis, should I provide the whole data(prev_data+new_data) to the loaded model? or should I provide only the new data?